# Python Abstract Proper Way of Calling Library Imported in Base Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abc

What is the proper way of utilizing functions that are imported in the base class of an abstract class? For example: in `base.py` I have the following:

```
import abc
import functions 

class BasePizza(object):
    __metaclass__  = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_ingredients(self):
         """Returns the ingredient list."""
```

Then I define the method in `diet.py`:

```
import base

class DietPizza(base.BasePizza):
    @staticmethod
    def get_ingredients():
        if functions.istrue():
            return True
        else:
            retrun False
```

However, if I try to run

```
python diet.py
```

I get the following:

```
NameError: name 'functions' is not defined
```

How can I get `diet.py` to recognize libraries imported by `base.py`?

Comment: What's wrong with either importing the module again or delegating to a method instead?

Comment: ... you say `from base import functions`

Comment: also `import base.py` is not valid python I think .... unless your file layout is really really wonky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract methods do not concern themselves with the *implementation details*.

If you need a specific module for your specific concrete implementation, you'll need to import this in your module:

```
import base
import functions


class DietPizza(base.BasePizza):
    @staticmethod
    def get_ingredients():
        return functions.istrue()
```

Note that a module import in multiple places *doesn't cost anything extra*. Python re-uses the already created module object when a module is used in multiple other modules.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to be sure of the proper procedure for this. No good learning incorrect methods.